# speech Recoginition in python

Tags: python-3.x

$ pip install speechRecoginition
Collecting speechRecoginition
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement speechRecoginition (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for speechRecoginition

Comment: You misspelled speechRecognition.

Answer (score 0):

You spell Recognition wrong and added an `i`. Therefore, pip cannot find a package with a misspelled name. try:

```
pip install -U speechRecognition
```

Answer (score 0):

raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

how I install PyAudio